# Ignite Cache entries not evicted if inserted via SQL

Tags: ignite

Looks like the data is not getting evicted from the Ignite cache in spite of the expiration time set into the configuration. I notice that this issue happens **when I use SQL** to insert data into the cache table.

```
 emplCache.query(new SqlFieldsQuery(
   "CREATE TABLE Employee (id LONG PRIMARY KEY, firstName VARCHAR, lastName VARCHAR, 
    salary DECIMAL, gender VARCHAR)")).getAll();
 SqlFieldsQuery insertqry = new SqlFieldsQuery("INSERT INTO Employee (id, firstName,
    lastName, salary, gender) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
 emplCache.query(insertqry.setArgs(Long.toString(count), words[1], words[2],
    words[3], words[4])).getAll();
```

This was how I configured the expiry :

```
CacheConfiguration<?, ?> cfg = new CacheConfiguration<>(cacheName);
    cfg.setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED);
    cfg.setName(cacheName);
    cfg.setSqlSchema("PUBLIC");
    cfg.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.ATOMIC);
    cfg.setExpiryPolicyFactory(CreatedExpiryPolicy.factoryOf(new Duration(SECONDS, 1)));
```

However, **I do not see this issue if I use the dataStreamer** to insert the data.

```
IgniteDataStreamer<Integer, Employee> stmr = ignite.dataStreamer(cfg.getName())
 stmr.addData(id, emp);
```

Have I missed some configuration setting?

[PS] Tried the following after Evgenii's answer:

```
// This is a util method that returns a cache config for the given cache name and the expiry time in seconds
        CacheConfiguration<?, ?> cfg = CacheConfig.getCacheConfig("emplCache", 1);
        IgniteCache<?, ?> emplCache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(cfg);
        emplCache.query(new SqlFieldsQuery(
                    "CREATE TABLE Employee (id LONG PRIMARY KEY, firstName VARCHAR, lastName VARCHAR, salary DECIMAL, gender VARCHAR)"
                    + "WITH \"template=emplCache\" ")).getAll();
```

Now i get this exception that the cache doesn't exist. But I am trying to create the table after creating the cache:

```
 Exception in thread "main" javax.cache.CacheException: class org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.IgniteSQLException: Cache doesn't exist: emplCache
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxy.query(IgniteCacheProxy.java:807)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxy.query(IgniteCacheProxy.java:765)
at com.demo.ignite.svc.CsvStreamer.main(CsvStreamer.java:33)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.IgniteSQLException: Cache doesn't exist: emplCache
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.ddl.DdlStatementsProcessor.convert(DdlStatementsProcessor.java:277)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.ddl.DdlStatementsProcessor.runDdlStatement(DdlStatementsProcessor.java:221)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.queryDistributedSqlFields(IgniteH2Indexing.java:1331)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor$5.applyx(GridQueryProcessor.java:1815)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor$5.applyx(GridQueryProcessor.java:1813)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.lang.IgniteOutClosureX.apply(IgniteOutClosureX.java:36)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.executeQuery(GridQueryProcessor.java:2293)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.querySqlFields(GridQueryProcessor.java:1820)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxy.query(IgniteCacheProxy.java:795)
```

Comment: Please share cache config where you configure EvictionPolicy

Comment: Edited my question to include the exact configurations that I have set in the code. I have not done any more configuration other than this. I assume that ExpiryPolicy is the same as EvictionPolicy. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table Employee will be created in another cache(that will be creted for it), thats why configured ExpiryPolicy will not be used.

```
To configure this new cache add "WITH \"template=CACHE_NAME\""
```

where CACHE_NAME is name of cache(or template) in your configuration. In your case it's cacheName;

For example, change your creation script to:

```
emplCache.query(new SqlFieldsQuery(
            "CREATE TABLE Employee (id LONG PRIMARY KEY, firstName VARCHAR, lastName VARCHAR, salary DECIMAL, gender VARCHAR) " +
                "WITH \"template=employee\" ")).getAll();
```

Here are [link to doc](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/distributed-ddl#section-create-table)

If you configure cache from java, you will need to add this cache with name emplCache to Ignite with:

```
    ignite.addCacheConfiguration(cfg);
```

Comment: I tried the "WITH \"template=CACHE_NAME\"" clause. I have updated my question with the exception I get.